# CMD command not working?

Tags: windows, cmd, dos, command-prompt

When i am running the command below on a folder on Desktop, it is working fine

```
cacls folder_name /e /p everyone:n
```

But, when i am trying to do the opposite on same folder i.e

```
cacls folder_name /e /p everyone:f
```

this is giving "Error : Access is Denied"
Why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your command terminal as admin? The best explanation for this is that you do not have full control on this folder for the user you are running under, so you cannot grant this privilege to others.

Comment: Actually, i am writing an .net application which runs this command as a part of its batch file. So how can i run a batch file as an administrator ??